# Weird crash on un-deallocated KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

This has been dogging me for a while.

I have a NSOperation subclass running in an operation queue. I have had occasional, infrequent (but significant portions of our crashes) instances of crashes on what looks like a key-value observer.

The crash looks like

```
Crashed: Thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x300000001099d05d
NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications.llvm.93060043671412

[OperationClass markAsFinished]
```

...Which strongly implies an un-deregistered KVO object. Problem is I can't find any references to KVO being added to this object. I've even gone to the trick of object swizzling to track calls to addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context: and there are no registrations to thse classes.

The only thing I can think of is something is implicitly registering a KVO, outside of the context of my source, but I don't know what would do this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You do have to be careful with KVO... Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632472/issues-with-nsoperationqueue-and-dealloc-being-called-and-crashing-app perhaps

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, so I can only talk in generalities, but if you look at the docs for [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation?language=objc) and [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue), you'll see that they use KVC and KVO for monitoring dependencies, priorities, and execution states. Based on the error statement, I'd say the code trying to send an 'Operation is Finished' notification that's being watched by KVO, and that's where things fall apart. Maybe an operation is pulled off the queue and deallocated before the notification goes through? Maybe a queue is deallocating before one of its operations finishes? Maybe an operation is deallocating before one of its dependencies completes? That's where I'd start looking, at any rate. Maybe put a breakpoint on the 'finished' property of NSOperation, see what comes up...

Comment: Right, I get that, but what I'm saying is that there is no evidence, in either source code or dynamically watching addObserver instances, that KVO ever registers a watcher for the finished state of the class. Until it crashes. One thing I was wondering is if there's some OS-level implicit registration that I'm not seeing.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether there is executable code that is invisible to lldb (Xcode's debugger), and while that seems unlikely to me, I can't really answer it with assurance. It seems *more* likely to me that the opaque, private workings of Operations and Queues are setting up KVO through some avenue *other than* the high-level addObserver: method, so you're just not looking in the right place. At any rate, I'm not sure how fruitful this line of inquiry is. You *know* the KVO is there; you need to find the dead object. Do you have NSZombies enabled?

Comment: Actually I was saying the latter, I wonder if there is any private workings of any internal APIs that set up KVO in ways that were opaque to me.  NSZombies would be useful obviously, except the crash, as I noted earlier, is infrequent and only comes to me in apple / crashlytics reports.